# Determine the throughput between 2 hosts from the bandwidth?

Tags: networking, bandwidth, throughput, mininet, iperf

I'm using mininet and I must observe the throughput between two hosts by using iperf.

```
mininet> iperf h1 h3
*** Iperf: testing TCP bandwidth between h1 and h3 
*** Results: ['14.3 Mbits/sec', '20.3 Mbits/sec']
```

What I don't understand is how to determine the actual throughput because here I am given bandwidth as the result.

Here is how I set up my topology:

```
sudo mn --topo linear,5 --link tc,bw=20,delay=50ms
```

How can I get the throughput from the result above?

Comment: Same thing. What you're given is the TCP throughput.

Comment: is it '14.3 Mbits/sec' or '20.3 Mbits/sec?